# How to Convert .sql of Mysql to postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

My Question is the following how to convert .sql 
mysql to postgresql sql , so I can uploaded to postgresql database at heroku 
and please let it be free tool.

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here are two tools for migrating from MySQL, both are actively maintained:

1) pgloader https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader. With it, conversion is just a one line:

```
pgloader mysql://user@localhost/dbname_in_mysql postgresql:///dbname_in_postgres
```

2) pg_chameleon https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pg_chameleon – this one is actually a replication system so it's suitable for systems under load.